# How to make an ipyleaflet/leaflet style app for custom maps of very local areas -- scale of tens of meters?

Tags: python, leaflet, maps, ipyleaflet

I realize this is a simplistic question, but I'm having trouble finding the right python library, essentially. I want to create an interactive map application with a lot of the basic functionality of a leaflet app. But leaflet is aimed at big, geographic scales, maps of countries and such. And strongly encourages using map providers like openstreetmap.org. *I* want something that maps plantings in an estate's gardens, or even a suburban yard. The complete map might represent an area of, oh, 300-400 square meters.

So, can anyone point me to a discussion of how to create small-scale maps like that that could be used by leaflet and ipyleaflet? Or alternatively a python library that would do the same things as leaflet? There's no real reason why this has to be in the leaflet family.

tia